# Nest TypeScript error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ChildService

Tags: typescript, ts-jest

I have a class structure something like this:

I have a ChildModule inside the libs/childmodule/src/child.module.ts. I have a taconfig.json which this is mapped to `@app`.

Then I have a parentModule where I am trying to import the ChildModule. Codewise:

`ChildModule`:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ChildService } from './child.service';
import { LoggerModule } from '@app/logger';
import { CommonModule } from '@app/common';
import { SecretsModule } from '@app/secrets';

@Module({
  providers: [ChildService],
  exports: [ChildService],
  imports: [
    LoggerModule,
    CommonModule,
    SecretsModule,
  ],
})
export class ChildModule {}
```

My `ParentModule` is as follows:

```js
import { ChildModule } from '@app/child';

@Module({
  imports: [SomeModule, LoggerModule, ChildModule],
  controllers: [ParentController],
  providers: [ParentService],
  exports: [ParentService],
})
export class ParentModule {}
```

I even did not used this `ChildSevice` yet through DI.

The error I am getting:

```
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ChildService (LoggerService, CommonService, ?). Please make sure that the argument SecretsService at index [2] is available in the ChildModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If SecretsService is a provider, is it part of the current ChildModule?
- If SecretsService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within ChildModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing SecretsService */ ]
  })
```

The best I know if I can import a module (ChildModule in my case) into parent, then all of ChildModule dependencies will be resolved. I mean I need not to manually keep on mention in my parent module's providers all the dependencies of ChildModule.

Not able to get any clue what is missing here.

For further clarity, adding here the `SecretsModule`:

`SecretsModule`

```js
import { Global, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { SecretsService } from './secrets.service';
import { Module1Module, Module1Service } from '@app/module1';

@Global()
@Module({})
export class SecretsModule {
  static forRoot(some_key) {
    return {
      module: SecretsModule,
      imports: [Module1Module, ConfigModule],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: SecretsService,
          useFactory: async (
            configService: ConfigService,
            service1: Module1Service,
          ) => {
            const secretsService = new SecretsService(
              configService,
              service1,
              some_key,
            );
            await secretsService.init();
            return secretsService;
          },
          inject: [ConfigService, Module1Service],
        },
      ],
      exports: [SecretsService],
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: how can you `import { ChildModule }` I don't see any childModule exported here it is AuditModule ?

Comment: Corrected & updated. Basically here is the hierarchy: ParentModule -> ChildModule -> Some other dependent modules like LoggersModule, CommonModule, SecretsModule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter in the `ChildService` constructor is `SecretsService`. The `SecretsService` probably is in `SecretsModule`. So to have the `SecretsService` in the `ChildModule` context, you need to put the service as an *exporter* in `SecretsModule`, then you can use this service in every module that you would want by importing the related module.

So the changes would be:

```ts
//secrets.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [...],
  controllers: [...],
  providers: [...],
  exports: [SecretsService],
})
export class SecretsModule {}
```

Do the same thing if you have any other case like this.

---

**Updated:**

Since `SecretsModule` is a dynamic module, you need to call `forRoot` in each module you would want to import `SecretModule`, otherwise, Nest couldn't import it.

```ts
//child.module.ts
@Module({
  providers: [ChildService],
  exports: [ChildService],
  imports: [
    LoggerModule,
    CommonModule,
    SecretsModule.forRoot(/*since forRoot take parameter `some_key`, you need to pass it here*/),
  ],
})
export class ChildModule {}
```

Comment: Thanks @mostafa-fakhraei. My `SecretsModule` already has the `SecretsServices` as exports.
I just added my `SecretsModule` into my original question. 
Any help will be helpful.

Comment: Ok, `SecretsModule` is a dynamic module and you need to change your code, so Nest can create an instance of it. I've updated my answer.